# plotyy function showing two x-axes but only want one

Tags: matlab

I am using the plotyy function to produce the chart in the image below.

[image: My Chart]

I have two issues with this chart. First issue being having two x-axes I want the zero on the left hand side of my chart to be level with the zero on the right hand side. Is there anyway I can make this happen?

Lastly I want to put some labels on the x-axis however you can that I labels have numbers on top of them. I only want the labels to be visible which I cannot seem to do?

Below is my code.

```
 x_labels = data_cell(2:end, 1);
 risk_tot = cell2mat(data_cell(2:end, 2));
 risk_cont = cell2mat(data_cell(2:end, 3));

 [pp,h1,h2]=plotyy((1:length(risk_tot)),risk_tot,(1:length(risk_tot)),risk_cont,'bar','stem');

 set(gca,'XtickL',x_labels);
 set(h1,'FaceColor',my_Blue2(40,:),'EdgeColor',my_Blue2(40,:))
 set(h2,'Color',my_Orange(1,:),'LineWidth',0.5,'MarkerEdgeColor',my_Orange(1,:))

 set(pp(1),'Box','off')
 set(pp(2),'Box','off')
```

**Update**

I have managed to resolve the second issue with the x-axis labels. I simply added the line below. This sets the second x-axis labels to empty.

Still can't fix the first issue.

```
set(pp(2),'XTickLabel',[]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`linkaxes`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html):

```
linkaxes(pp,'y')
```

You may need to adjust the axes limits with `pp(1).Ylim = ...` to get the desired result.

Comment: thanks I now have just the one x-axis. However it has cut off part of my chart (one variable is annoyingly rather large). I tried  using pp(1).Ylim = y2_max; However got an error message 'Structure assignment to non-structure object.'

Comment: I think the `pp(1).Ylim` syntax only applies to the latest release (R2014b). For older releases, I think it's something like `set(pp(1),'Ylim',[0 y2_max])` if my memory serves me well. The downside of linking the axes if you have two axes of different magnitudes, is that one plot is going to look rather small...